# "Synonyms" of classes

Tags: java, class, synonym

For the sake of an example I have a `WAV` class which represents WAV sound files. For convenience' sake, I am then required to add a class called `WaveformAudioFile` which has exactly the same functionality.

Regardless of possible design/style issues, what would be an appropriate way to integrate the new class ? By using an extends (with nothing added), by using a common interface or something else ?

Edit: Thinking of this further, if design was to be considered would there be an alternative to avoid redundant code ? I mean writing interfaces would be tiresome if there are several classes. Some sort of pattern that could be used to init. attributes ?

Comment: I prefer Interfaces to define Contracts. I usually view Sub-types as an Implementation Detail to aid with "Code Re-use" ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** From design point of view, if you want **your classes to play a specific role, then go for Interface.**

**2.** If you have **behaviors that keeps changing**, then its better to **encapsulate them in either Abstract class or Interface** , then extend or implement it to specify certain functionality.

//////////////////////////////////////////**Edited :**//////////////////////////////

I think you are referring to the **DRY principle (Dont Repeat Yourself)**, according to this principle, **its better to keep your Information and Behaviors in Single Sensible Place**.

But what if the Behaviors are different for different classes for the same functionality.

For eg:

Consider `Painting` as a **Class** with `paint() Method`.

Now

**paint() method can have Stroking, gliding, shading etc styles of doing it.**

Then its **better to Encapsulate that method into an Abstract class or an Interface**.

```
public interface Paint{

paintDoIt(String style);

}
```

Its **Not about a tiresome work**, but about **flexibility and having the capability to make changes without touching too many classes and without breaking the code**.

**Only One thing is a Constant in Software Engineering and that is** `CHANGE`.

So we need to adopt to it.

Comment: I get you for n°2. Something like the template pattern. If you're willing to give this some more thought I've added to the question.

Comment: I have edited my answer for further details..see the Edited part

Comment: Great. I appreciate it when someone "paints" things out as you have done. It gives some guidelines to follow.

Comment: Thank you for elaborating. Also, I kind of like this phrase :) : "Only One thing is a Constant in Software Engineering and that is CHANGE".

Answer (score 2):

Interface is the best solution from my point of view. Declare a common interface for classes who implement such functionality and use this interface instead of direct class type definition.

For instance:

```
ISoundFile mySoundFile = getSoundFile();
```

Where `ISoundFile` is your declared interface.

Comment: Thank you. I've added to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use a common `interface` and implement it in both of the classes. One major benifit is your WAVE and all classes then can extend any other classes also .

Comment: Thanks. I've added more to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding this as it might interest someone. I've thought of another solution and that's to simply use a wrapper class :) .